# Dynamically load TLS certificates per request in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate

In our Spring Boot based application we use multitenancy and configure per-tenant JWT validation with `HttpFilter` receiving Issuer URI and JWK set URI within request headers:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtPreAuthorizationConfigurer extends HttpFilter {
    private final OAuth2ResourceServerProperties properties;

    @Override
    protected void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws Exception {
        tenantContext.setIssuerUri(request.getHeader(Headers.ISSUER_URI.getName()));
        tenantContext.setJwkSetUri(request.getHeader(Headers.JWK_SET_URI.getName()));
        super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
    }
}
```

Now we need to go further and be able to configure TLS per-tenant either. In other words at runtime we need to be able to decide which certificate we pick from certificate store and use:

- if the request comes from client A we use certificate A
- if the request comes from client B we use certificate B
- etc.

This is the part of `application.yml` responsible for SSL configuration:

```java
server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: "classpath:my-keystore.p12"
    key-store-password: p4ssw0rd
    key-store-type: PKCS12
```

Can this be achieved with means of Spring Boot somehow? E.g. something like

```java
public class TLSPerRequestConfigurer extends HttpFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws Exception {
        var tenantName = request.getHeader(Headers.TENANT_NAME.getName()));
        // use tenantName
        super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
    }
}
```

P.S. The application is containerized with Kubernetes and deployed into AWS, so other possible non-Spring suggestions are welcome.

Comment: HTTPS works by (1) doing the TLS handshake, which includes selecting and sending the certificate, to establish a private (encrypted) and authenticated channel, then (2) sending the HTTP request, including headers, over that channel. Note 1 occurs before 2 and 2 occurs after 1. No program, not springboot nor express nor python nor anything else, can possibly read any header in 2 before making the certificate choice in 1. If you get the clients to issue requests to different _server names_ and have different cert&keys for those server names, that can work using SNI.